# AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'list object' has no attribute

Tags: ansible, jinja2

Yaml template

```
bgp:
      local: 109
      remote: 109
      site:
         - neighbor:
              peer_ip: [ 172.16.110.3, 172.16.110.4 ]
           vpnv4:
              vrf: Site-1
              network: 109.10.1.1
              mask: 255.255.255.0
         - neighbor:
              peer_ip: [ 172.16.120.3, 172.16.120.4 ]
           vpnv4:
              vrf: Site-2
              network: 109.10.1.1
              mask: 255.255.255.0
```

Jinja2 template

```
router bgp {{ item.bgp.local }}
{% for i in item.bgp.site %}
 address-family ipv4 vrf {{ i.vpnv4.vrf }}
 network {{ i.vpnv4.network }} mask {{ i.vpnv4.mask }}
{% for b in item.bgp.site.neighbor.peer_ip %}
 neighbor {{ b }} remote-as {{ item.bgp.remote }}
 neighbor {{ b }} activate
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

If I remove this it works. I am suspecting an issue with "list" but no idea how to fix it.

```
{% for b in item.bgp.site.neighbor.peer_ip %}
 neighbor {{ b }} remote-as {{ item.bgp.remote }}
 neighbor {{ b }} activate
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Which list are you referring to? How are you invoking ansible?

Answer (score 1):

`item.bgp.site` is actually `i` of your outer loop.

Try: `{% for b in i.neighbor.peer_ip %}`